# Sum of probability differential is zero

Tags: probability, summation, statistical-mechanics

I keep seeing:

$$
\sum_i [ln(p_i) + 1]dp_i = \sum_i ln(p_i)dp_i
$$

where $p_i$ is the probability of the $i^{th}$ state and where

$ \sum_i p_i = 1 $

cropping up in my statistical mechanics course. I'm a bit unsure of how one comes to this?

EDIT: A similar result which confuses me is:

$$
\sum_i [ln(Z)] dp_i = 0
$$

where $Z$ is the partition function.

Comment: At fixed $\sum_i p_i$ whatever you add to some $p_i$ you have to subtract from some (other) $p_{i'}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the total change in p (which is $ \sum_i dp_i $) will always work out to be zero. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably because we always have $ \sum_i p_i = 1$: if we differentiate this condition,
$$ \sum_i dp_i = 0 $$
so that the total probability remains $1$. It's like $\dot{x} \cdot x = 0 $ when $x$ is forced to lie on a sphere $x \cdot x = R^2$.

Comment: Yes, this coupled with Fabian's point convinced me. Thanks both of you. Have you any idea of my edit?

Comment: Wait, I just realised that $ln(Z)$ is a constant. You can take it out the sum and the answer above applies. Okay, I'm accepting then.